# Finding unique paths in a 5X5 grid

Tags: java, path-finding

We have a 5X5 grid with each grid labelled with a unique number. We are given 5 different pair of grids. The task that needs to performed is to find unique paths between all the 5 different pair of grids subject to following condition :

1. The entire 5X5 grid must be covered.

2. Paths must not overlap.

Consider for example the grids are numbered from 1-25.
we are given any 5 different pair of grids as

1 22

4 17

5 18

9 13

20 23

The expected output is

1 6 11 16 21 22

4 3 2 7 12 17

5 10 15 14 19 18

9 8 13

20 25 24 23

we need to print the unique paths for each pair fulfilling above stated conditions.

here is the messy code i've developed so far but no where close to getting any closer to the solution.

```
static StringBuffer findpath(int[][] grid, int index[][]){
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    int[][] paths = new int[5][5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            paths[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int l=0;l<2;l++){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(index[l][0] == grid[i][j])
                    paths[i][j] = 1;
                if(index[l][1] == grid[i][j])
                    paths[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }

    }

    int x=0,y=0,target = 0;
    for(int l=0;l<2;l++){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(index[l][0] == grid[i][j]){
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    target = index[l][1];
                }
            }
        }

    gridUtil(grid, x, y, target, paths,s);
        s.append(grid[x][y]);
        s.append("\n");
    }

    return s;

}
static boolean doesnotoverlap(int[][] paths, int x, int y){
    if(x>=0 && x<5 && y>=0 && y<5 && paths[x][y] == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
static void printpath(StringBuffer s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
static boolean gridUtil(int grid[][], int x, int y, int target, int paths[][],StringBuffer s){
    if(x<5 && y<5 && grid[x][y] == target)
    {   paths[x][y] = 1;
        s.append(target+" ");
        return true;
    }
        int in = 0;
        //System.out.println(gridUtil(grid, Math.abs(x+1), y, target, paths, s));
        if(doesnotoverlap(paths, x+1, y)){
            System.out.println("here1");
            paths[x][y] = 1;
            s.append(grid[x][y]+" ");
            in = s.indexOf(Integer.toString(grid[x][y]));
            if(gridUtil(grid, Math.abs(x+1), y, target, paths, s))
            return true;
        }
        if(doesnotoverlap(paths, x-1, y)){
            System.out.println("here");
            paths[x][y] = 1;
            s.append(grid[x][y]+" ");
            in = s.indexOf(Integer.toString(grid[x][y]));
            if(gridUtil(grid, Math.abs(x-1), y, target, paths, s))
            return true;
        }
        if(doesnotoverlap(paths, x, y+1)){
            paths[x][y] = 1;
            s.append(grid[x][y]+" ");
            in = s.indexOf(Integer.toString(grid[x][y]));
            if(gridUtil(grid, Math.abs(x),  Math.abs(y+1), target, paths, s))
            return true;
        }
        if(doesnotoverlap(paths, x, y-1)){
            paths[x][y] = 1;
            s.append(grid[x][y]+" ");
            in = s.indexOf(Integer.toString(grid[x][y]));
            if(gridUtil(grid, Math.abs(x),  Math.abs(y-1), target, paths, s))
            return true;
        }
        paths[x][y] = 0;
        //System.out.println(in);
        //s.deleteCharAt(in);
        return false;



}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] grid = new int[5][5];
    int[][] index = new int[5][2];
    int fill=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            fill = fill + 1;
            grid[i][j] = fill;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            index[i][j] = sc.nextInt();

        }
    }


    StringBuffer s = findpath(grid, index);
    System.out.println(s);





}
```

}

Comment: Please ask a specific question or describe a particular problem you are having. You could for example, share outputs of your program in contrast with the desire output, etc. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is i'm not getting anywhere close to solving this problem. No idea on how to do this task.

Comment: Is that code yours? If it is, you should be able to edit your question with it's output so far. This is not a "make my code work" kind of site, you should try harder to provide context and examples to your question. Otherwise is equally harder to other users to help you :|

Comment: I have edited the question with the desired output. Please help now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Approximation Algorithm for non-intersecting paths in a grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080969/approximation-algorithm-for-non-intersecting-paths-in-a-grid)